# heroku push error with deleted gem in temp folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

i am getting this error while running git  push heroku master

```
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
remote:        (in /tmp/build_c74d6e694d63ef677ca6d5b277349b45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/polymer-core-rails-0.2.0/app/assets/components/core-animated-pages/demos/news.html)
```

I have removed polymer gem but it is still giving problem 
I also tried to run rake asset:precompile and its not giving any error 
but heroku push showing same error

Comment: Remove the `app/assets/components` & `vendor/assets/components` folders and the `application.html` created by running `rails g polymer:install` step. That includes removing `//= require polymer/webcomponents` line from `application.js`. After that, make sure you have committed the changes before pushing to heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your pre-compiled files under public/assets folder of your local environment and push to heroku again. Hope it works.